# Rescale integer percentages to a smaller integer scale while guaranteeing normalization

Tags: probability, integers

Say I have a set $Q$ of integers between $0$ and $100$. As a constraint, the arithmetic sum of all elements adds up to $100$. We can interpret this as an "integer probability space".

Now, I wish to renormalize the elements of $Q$ to an integer between $0$ and $8$ (the use of a rounding function will be required). Can I ensure that the sum of the rescaled integers sum to $8$?

---

For instance; say the elements of $Q$ are $\{50,30,20\}$. First, let's verify that they sum to $100$: $50+30+20=100$, ok!. Now, I renormalize them to a scale on $0$ to $8$, and I get

$$
50/100 \to 4/8\\
30/100\to 2.4/8\\
20/100\to 1.6/8
$$

To promote (demote?) the new elements to an integer, I $Round$ the values and I get $4/8,2/8,2/8$ which sums to $8$. Good!

However, If I instead chose a different renormalization scale (say $5$ instead of $8$), then the possibility exists that my rescale breaks the normalization condition. For instance, the elements would rescale as follows: 
$$
50/100\to 2.5/5 \\
30/100 \to 1.5/5 \\
20/100 \to 1/5
$$
Rounding them I get $3/5+2/5+1/5=6/5$, and the normalization is broken.

In the case of $8$ it does not seem possible that the normalization condition be broken by rounding the re-scaling. We can see this because $0.5/8=6.25%$, $1.5/8= 18.75%$, etc. Since the mid value on the $8$-scale cannot produce integer values on the $100$-scale, it thus appears that the problem of breaking the normalization cannot occur as a result of the application of the rounding function.

---

Can someone see anything wrong with my analysis?

Comment: What if you take all the integers in $Q$ equal to $1$?

Comment: @mjez Equal to $100$, not to $1$. I hold $Q$ to define an integer probability space normalized to $100$.

Comment: Ok, I guess that you do not really need $Q$ to be a set, so that you could ``$Q = \{1,\dots,1\}$''.

Comment: @mjez Well the elements of $Q$ are given by the problem. Say you throw a coin, then you have $50$ chances of having head and $50$ chances of having tail on the 100-scale. In this case $Q=\{50,50 \}$.

Comment: Then, I do not understand what your question is. I just pointed out that, for a certain choice of $Q$, you could break the normalization.

Comment: @mjez so special handling is required for small values. Say we restrict the values of the initial set from $13$ to $100$. In this case, all small values retain the original scale, but the higher values can be re-normalized to the smaller case. We are basically recovering the definition of a float in programming.